# BCD full adder subtraction and addition

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, design

I want to design a circuit that takes as input two decimal digits binary coded as A1…4 and subtractionB1…4 and displays their , sum or (fulldifference using a two place BCD-to-7-segment display as selected by a signal C
:
A BCD adder)/subtractor.

I use full adder(s), (and), (xor) and (or) gates,  Also I used input C  carry in for subtraction, but the BCD circuit doesn't work like the way I want. When I use the A1 and B1 inputs, the result at the outputs will be incorrect . The other inputs work well. When I use carry, the subtraction of inputs, gives me an incorrect output value

The outputs can't be bigger than 15 in the process of additio,and cannot be negative in the subtraction process.

For example when I put 4+6 in inputs, the result of output will be 10. When I put 8+8, the result, the output will be 15. For some reasons the output cannot give me numbers bigger than 15.

In the process of subtractor, can't gives me negative numbers. For example, when I put 1-2 in inputs, the output will gives me 6.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BCD adder and subtractor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/653067/bcd-adder-and-subtractor)

Comment: Yes, I modified the circuit a little, but another problem appeared

Comment: If i put 4+5 in inputs, the outputs will be 9. But when i put 8+8 in inputs, than outputs will be 15. the outputs cannot  gives me number bigger than 15 for some reasons.

Comment: yes i running my simulations. I can look my logic values on the wires when i put 7-segment

Comment: the schematic is incorrect.  why did you choose this schematic?  can you post a link to any reference material you used in choosing this schematic?

Comment: I didn't find the schematic better than this. I made this schematic from some website and youtube. i asked my teacher but he don't know what is the problem with this schematic. this is better schematic i can make now.

Comment: @toolic It appears that the page you quote has been removed. I get 404,

Comment: 1) Get a 1+1 digit BCD adder to work. Show result with a two place 7-segment display. 2) Get a 1-1 digit BCD subtracter to work. 3) combine adder&subtracter.

Comment: @PeterJennings: That's because the OP deleted that question and you do not have privileges to see deleted questions.

Comment: @Mohammed How do you expect to illustrate a "-1" result? Do you need a sign? Or is this just an absolute-value display?

Comment: I'm thinking of putting an LED indicator that shows whether the signal is positive or negative, I haven't figured it out yet, I want to solve the addition problem first.

Comment: @Mohammed Any thoughts given the answer I've provided? It presents the methods you'll need to apply. Do you understand what I wrote?

Comment: I almost understood your answer, but I'm thinking how to apply your solutions in the simulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial addition portion:

[image]

... is just fine. You've got that right. And it's standard practice. You should be able to see that the 5 bits exiting the output will obey the usual rules.

For example, in the case you mentioned, of 8 + 8, you should see that the carry out will be **1** while the remaining four bits are all **0**. And in the other case you mentioned, 1 - 2, you should see the carry out is **0** and the other four bits are all **1**.

That's what should happen in 4-bit binary.

But:

1. A problem comes in when displaying a result. For example, if the carry out is **0** and you are subtracting, then the result is a negative value and you need to display a **-**, somehow. You need a way to show that the result is negative. I gather from your comments (not stated in the question) that you are thinking of just using an LED to indicate this.
2. Another problem is that for subtraction where negative results occur, you need to convert that back to an absolute value -- which means complementing it back and adding **1** again -- in order to generate the lower digit needed to be displayed (with a minus sign, somehow.)
3. A final problem comes during addition and when anything over the value of the value of 2*4+1=9 is generated. In this case, 2*3=6 must be added. (Since the lower bit is **0**, this really means adding 3 to the middle 3 bits.) Suppose you have the output of 10 (01010.) Then to generate a BCD output you add 00110 to that: 01010 + 00110 = 10000. This gives the BCD result of **1** and **0** that you need to show 10 on the display. (Note that this operation has to occur whether the result is positive or negative, but that it must occur ***after*** step 2 has been dealt with and not beforehand.)

What's the plan to achieve the above?

Here's my thought. (Which also includes *greybeard*'s note that I already know to expect a **1** in the tens display when I'm adding 3 in the 2nd 7483. So one less gate needed, now. Thanks!)

> [image]

Comment: You already generate a signal *decimal carry in addition*: this is the LSB of the more significant digit, you don't need to recompute it from S1…4, saving at least the *uppermost AND with one inverted input*.

Comment: @greybeard Okay. Thanks. I think I see my folly. Yeah. If I'm adding 3 (6), then it must be because I expect to see a 1 in the tens digit. (I'm an idiot!) I'll make the adjustment. And thanks!

Comment: @greybeard I think the questioner is stuck with 7483s, whether mentally or by outside requirements. I've not used the 4000 series devices. (Too expensive, too few in variety, too difficult to find, and I never did lay hands on an RCA databook back when I was in my multi-board wire-wrapping days.) And thanks again for the kick in the head!

Comment: I tried your design, it can give me output 9 + 9 = 18, but for some reasons the output can't give me 17 and 1, and another problem if i put 0-8 it gave me -7, also it give me hexadecimal number in subtractor

Comment: @Mohammed Then you didn't get the right schematic. Here's [the 0 - 8 = -8 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu4ft.png). You can see it works fine. And here's [the 9+8 = 17 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxbKz.png). It also works fine. I've thoroughly checked it out. It works in every single case. I also automated the testing, as well. It's possible you may need to learn a little more about your simulator.

Comment: I had some errors in connecting the circuit, I fixed the problem and it works as it should, but can you show me 0-10 = -10? because it will show me a hexadecimal

Comment: @Mohammed I didn't design this for binary. You mentioned **BCD**.

Comment: @Mohammed [Here's an example that will handle 0 - 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwpyY.png).

Comment: i thaink of using extra adder to make condition to make nuamebr smailler than -9, add (and,or) gates to new full adder

Comment: @Mohammed That may not be needed. It's just in this case you need to turn on the line going to the 2nd adder's A1 and A2 inputs, for the negative case. I'd excluded that. But it can be included.

Comment: @Mohammed So here's the central questions you need to answer. (1) *Are these 4-bit iinputs limited to BCD-only?* If not limited and instead they are binary, then you need to answer another question: (2) *Are they both signed binary or both unsigned binary (or some other mixture of those)?* All these things matter before a design can be generated.

Comment: it's 4-bit iinputs limited to BCD-only, to hoenst i don't understand how you make -10, but i put Comparator 74LS83D, if A>B when B=9 at the output will be 1 in double-digit , but the output gaves me (-1A), the problem is in The unit digit.

Comment: @Mohammed Then you just need to understand that while a simulator may allow you to change the bits so that the B input is 10 and the A input is zero, when subtracting, that having B=10 is not legal. The simulator doesn't care about "legal". All it cares about is that you have 4 bits and this means anything from 0 to 15 is fine. But ***you*** know that BCD can only be up to 9. So B must be only from 0 to 9, not 0 to 15.

Comment: i know the BCD is from 0 to 9, but my question how can i delete hexadecimal numbers? i want the 7-segment  get 0 when B (1010)  in minus And the counting begins again, should i put a new Full adder?

Comment: @Mohammed You can't delete them. You just don't simulate them. You are in control. Do it manually. Why do you permit a 1010 in B? Just don't do it.